# Typescript interface for a class method error

Tags: typescript

Why do I get error "the string is not assignable to iGreet" ?

```
  interface iGreet {
    (p: string ): string
  }


  class C {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
      this.greeting = message;
    }

    greet(p: string): iGreet {
      return "Hello, " + this.greeting + " " + p;
    } 
  }

  let greeter = new C("world");
  console.log(greeter.greet("test"))
```

Comment: You're saying the method `greet` should return an `iGreet`, but right now it returns a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`greet(p: string): iGreet` is saying this function *returns* `iGreet`. If you want to annotate the type of `greet`, you'll need to use an assignment like this:

```
greet: iGreet = function (p) {
    // ...
}
```